# Ikea Tradfri Gateway don't connect to a network

Tags: smart-home, ikea-tradfri, apple-homekit

I connect my Ikea Tradfri to a router. All three lights are on, but the App can't found the gateway.
I use an IP scanner on my Mac, and I can't found Gateway.
The app suggested that if I am sure that Gateway is connected to the same network (and it is)

I found a solution on the net, connecting Tradfri Gateway on mac, and shared the internet. This way, I can see the Gateway on IP Scanner, but the app still doesn't work.

What is the problem...

Comment: Do you see a link light (matching the port it's plugged into) on the router when it's plugged in? Also the router admin panel normally should give you a list of what devices have been issues what addresses, worth looking there. Without knowing more about your network setup it's hard offer more advice. I'd normally start with some network packet capture

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see the admin panel of my router (my provider locked it). The lights are up. That's why I use IP scanner on Mac - I can't see the device. Is there a port or rule that need to be opened for Tradfrie,...

Answer (score 1):

After contacting the internet provider, I found out, that there are two types of ports - internal and external ports. TV needs external port but Gateway needs internal one.

After connecting to internal ports it works.